# Why does my output display turn 1 instead of turn 11 when I load game after saving?

Tags: python

[image of output after saving and loading turn 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fidv.png)

```
def save_game(buildings,building_count,turn):
    f = open('data.txt', 'w')
    f.write('Turn {}\n'.format(turn))
    for i in range(len(board)):
        s = ''
        for j in range(len(board[i])):
            s += board[i][j] + ','
        f.write(s[:-1] + '\n')
    f.close()
    return buildings, building_count, turn
def load_game(buildings, building_count, turn):
    f = open('data.txt','r')
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        data = line.strip('\n').split(',')
        board.append(data)
    f.close()
    return buildings, building_count, turn
```

Please help me using file i\o, this is a school assignment and I am not allowed to use imports or anything, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your load game doesn't change the input parameters `buildings, building_count, turn` in any way.

I would suspect 1 is just the default value or a random initialized value for `turn`, when you call the `load_game` function.

You append something into `board`, wherever that is from. So the code in general seems wrong.

As a start I would not pass any parameters except maybe the file path to `load_game`. Initialize the variables in there and fill them with the correct values.

Regarding the turn count problem specifically:
For the first line you can read it in, split it into to parts by using `.split(' ')`. check if the first entry in the list is equal to `'Turn'` and read in the second one and parse it to an `int`.